# Java JButton two or more icons

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I would like to set two or more icons to one JButton (Java, Swing). Is it possible?

I add picture made in drawing. ;-)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is by creating a custom class that implements the `Icon` interface, which simply paints two given icons side by side.

```java
public class TwoIcon implements Icon {

    private final int iconGap = 2;
    private final Icon icon1;
    private final Icon icon2;

    public TwoIcon(final Icon icon1, final Icon icon2) {
        this.icon1 = icon1;
        this.icon2 = icon2;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        int mid = getIconHeight() / 2;
        int y1 = y + mid - icon1.getIconHeight() / 2;
        int y2 = y + mid - icon2.getIconHeight() / 2;
        icon1.paintIcon(c, g, x, y1);
        icon2.paintIcon(c, g, x + icon1.getIconWidth() + iconGap, y2);
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconWidth() {
        return icon1.getIconWidth() + icon2.getIconWidth() + iconGap;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconHeight() {
        return Math.max(icon1.getIconHeight(), icon2.getIconHeight());
    }
}
```

The icons will be painted side by side with a padding of `2` and centered vertically.
Play around with the spacing if you want them to be aligned differently.

```java
Icon leftIcon = ...
Icon rightIcon = ...
button.setIcon(new TwoIcon(leftIcon, rightIcon));
```

Result:
I am simply using Icons that paint a solid colour here. One is `16x16` and the other `20x20` in size to demonstrate the vertical alignment.

[image]

In fact this is not restricted to `JButton` and will for any `JComponent` that can use an icon e.g. `JLabel` etc.

Comment: (1+) See: [Compound Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/compound-icon/) for a more flexible class that provides many different options for combining icons.

Answer (score 1):

Are those two icons (happy / sad) literally the icons required? If so, I'd suggest instead using a `JCheckBox` and setting the icons as the default and selected icon (so the check box changes between them on selection).

Here's how (using a red icon for happy, and blue icon for sad).

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.net.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class CheckBoxWithIcons {

    private JComponent ui = null;
    Image happyImage;
    Image sadImage;

    CheckBoxWithIcons() {
        try {
            initUI();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public final void initUI() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        if (ui!=null) return;

        happyImage = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCF8S.png"));
        sadImage = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJmeJ.png"));

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4,4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4,100,4,100));

        JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("Mood", true);
        checkBox.setIcon(new ImageIcon(sadImage));
        checkBox.setSelectedIcon(new ImageIcon(happyImage));
        ui.add(checkBox);
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (Exception useDefault) {
            }
            CheckBoxWithIcons o = new CheckBoxWithIcons();

            JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

            f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
            f.pack();
            f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

            f.setVisible(true);
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```